# In "Jobs" what does Steve's boss mean when he tells him: "As for your personal issues, I think we may have a solution."

Tags: jobs

In the movie "Jobs", Steve's boss tells him people are complaining because he isn't showering, being an asshole, etc. He then says:

> As for your personal issues, I think we may have a solution.

It was said in the tone similar to "It's settled."

But nothing is said after that, it just cuts to Steve working on the "troublesome game" in the dark, before he calls Woz for help.

**What was the solution?**

Comment: By the way guys, not worthy of a new question but, did Steve Wozniak ("Woz") really make an early version of brick-breaker, or is that totally fiction?

Comment: Jobs' troublesome game that he was assigned was actually Breakout (brick-breaker). He was paid the bonus of $100 per chip that he could get rid of. Being stuck, he turned to Woz, who removed a total of 50 chips, earning a $5000 bonus. In the movie, the $5000 was the whole bonus, but in reality, the $5000 was the result of 50 chips @ $100 per chip. He gave Woz $350, instead of the $2500 due him. Atari had already designed breakout, they just needed it improved.

Comment: @CGCampbell nice, that's so cool to know. I saw where Woz talked about forgiving him for that, in an interview after he died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was the solution. His boss at Atari gave him the troublesome game to work on, at the same time that he 'rescheduled' his work hours to be after normal working hours. If he was no longer in the area during the day, no one had to put up with his being an asshole, or his body odor.
Out of sight, out of mind.

Comment: Ahh that crossed my mind but I thought he also could've been working late on the game. I get it.